# Changing the direction of the animation for a particular screen in StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to change the animation of navigation to `bottom-to-top` for a particular screen in the stack-navigator in **Navigation 5.0**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked for the answers in StackOverflow but didn't find a solution related to a single screen. So here's the solution if someone is looking for the answer.

`options={{cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forVerticalIOS}}`

```
import {  CardStyleInterpolators,createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

<AppStack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName={"Home"}>
          <AppStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <AppStack.Screen
            options={{
              cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forVerticalIOS,
            }}
            name="Edit"
            component={EditScreen}
          />
          <AppStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingScreen} />
        </>
      )}
</AppStack.Navigator>
```

Comment: If you want to use forVerticalIOS, but inverted instead, you can use it like this:
`cardStyleInterpolator: ({current, inverted, layouts}) => CardStyleInterpolators.forVerticalIOS({current: current, inverted: -1, layouts: layouts})`